# sed - * works, + doesnt?

Tags: sed

I'm renaming a bunch of music files, stripping of the track numbers using sed. However I'm puzzled by sed's behavior towards the '+' character for regex expressions.

What I wanted to do:

```
for f in *\-[0-9]**; do echo "$f" | sed 's/\-[0-9]+/\-/g'; done
```

But that didn't work as intended. This workaround did the job:

```
for f in *\-[0-9]**; do echo "$f" | sed 's/\-[0-9][0-9]*/\-/g'; done
```

However I would like to know what the issue is with using '+' in sed... Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`+` is an extended regular expression modifier. `sed` does [basic regular expressions](http://sed%20's/%5C-[0-9]+/%5C-/g') by default.

To make `sed` parse your expressions as extended regular expressions, use `sed -E`. GNU `sed` also understands `+` in basic regular expressions if you use it as `\+`.

Also, your pattern `*\-[0-9]**` looks strange. The `-` does not need escaping (not in the shell pattern and not in the regular expression), and unless you use `globstar` in `bash`, the `**` pattern will expand to itself.  With `globstar` enabled in `bash` `*-[0-9]**` would expand to all pathnames that contain `-N` in the first filename component (where `N` is a digit).

What I think you'd like to do is something like this (probably not quite, but I don't know what your filenames look like):

```
for name in *-[0-9][0-9]*; do
    newname=${name%-*}
    printf 'Would rename "%s" into "%s"\n' "$name" "$newname"
    # mv "$name" "$newname"
done
```

This matches all names in the current directory that contains `-NN` (`N` is a digit).  It strips off everything from the last `-` in the filename and renames the file (the actual renaming is commented out).

Comment: Ah yes, escaping is a GNU-ism...